# Plotting graphs using Matplotlib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to print the graph in different figures but all the graphs is overlapping. Here I have a for loop (third for loop) in my code and I am accessing the position of the `numpyArraysDisplay.size` and in `x` the counting of size stores.

Now first line counts from `0 to 44` and then second line counts and so on (size not fixed).

After that I am appending the `x` in a list named `position` and plotting the graph but for first line it save the figure of graph perfectly but for second line it overlaps to first one in same figure and so on.

But I want all the graphs in different figure for all the line. I have displayed figure of over lapped graphs.

I have written below code:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
from scipy.stats import entropy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

position = []
store_entropy = []  # Empty list defined to store the list of entropy
outputfile = open("Output.txt", "w")  # Output file open in write mode for saving the outputs

# Reading the csv file by reader
with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for line in reader:
        lines = filter(None, line[2:])
        lines1 = ' '.join(lines).split(',')

        # Loop for every rows in the file
        for row in lines1[::]:
            makeOneLine = row.rstrip('\n')
            delimiter = " "
            makeOneLine = delimiter.join(makeOneLine.split(delimiter, 3))
            # Makes Numpy Array of all the lines in the file
            numpyArraysDisplay = np.array(list(makeOneLine.split(" ")))
            # print(numpyArraysDisplay)
            outputfile.write(str(numpyArraysDisplay) + '\n')

            # Loop for defining the first segment of the the Numpy Arrays
            for x in range(numpyArraysDisplay.size):
                part1 = numpyArraysDisplay[:x + 1]  # First segment divide
                strings, counts = np.unique(part1, return_counts=True)
                # Counting the frequency of the words appearing in the file line by line
                CountWordsfrequency = np.array(list(dict(zip(strings, counts)).values()))
                # print(CountWordsfrequency)
                outputfile.write(str(CountWordsfrequency) + '\n')

                # Loop for finding the Probability and Entropy of the dialogue types
                for y in range(0, CountWordsfrequency.size):
                    probability = CountWordsfrequency[y] / part1.size
                    outputfile.write("Probability is : " + str(probability) + '\n')
                ent2 = entropy(counts, base=10)
                outputfile.write("Entropy is \t" + str(ent2) + '\n')
                # Store all the Entropies in a list for further work
                store_entropy.append(ent2)
            # print(store_entropy)
                position.append(x+1)
            print(position)
            plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))
            plt.plot(position, store_entropy, '-o')
            plt.xlabel("Segmentation Break Point")
            plt.ylabel("Entropy")
            plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(position) + 1, 1))
            plt.savefig('Plots/', figurewidth='25cm')
            plt.show()
            plt.clf()
size = len(store_entropy)
# One Line for loop and if condition to slipt the list by particular values as
# we have to give list inside list for passing particular index of entropy
idx_list = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(store_entropy) if val == 0.0]
res = [store_entropy[i: j] for i, j in zip([0] + idx_list, idx_list + ([size] if idx_list[-1] != 
size else []))]
# print(res)
# for loop and if condition for setting the lists of the Entropies index starting
# from zero instead of 1 and removing the empty lists created in the lists.
res2 = [x for x in res if x != []]
#print(res2)
# print("The List after Split:" + str(res))
#print(res2[0])
```

The output is as below:
[image: Overlapped image of graph]

But I want all the graphs on different figure.

Comment: Can you try to replace `plt.clf()` with `plt.cla()` or `plt.close()`?

Comment: @Guimoute : I have tried it but the problem remain same.

Answer (score 0):

In this above case when I have reviewed my code I found that if I want to pass the lists to `plt.plot()` then it is possible that we just pass the list variable. It automatic takes the index and values when we plot the graphs using for loops.

I have below solution and achieved the results.

```
for a, b in enumerate(res2):
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))
    plt.plot(b, '-*', color="red")
    plt.xlabel("Dialogue Act Types")
    plt.ylabel("Entropy")
    plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(b) + 1, 1))
    plt.savefig('Plots/', figurewidth='25cm')
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```